# Is it possible to convert an Android Studio App to IOS? (Java)

Tags: java, android, ios

So I'm currently developping an app in Android Studio, being Java the programming languague used. I wanted to know If It's possible to convert it later into IOS, and if so, how should i do it.

Thanks in advance for all responses.

Comment: You cannot. Why not try Flutter?

Comment: Does it work for both Android and IOS? How hard is it to learn?

Comment: short reason why it is not possible: Why would the world need iOS developers, if every Android app could be just *converted* into iOS app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Short Answer

You **cannot** convert all the project from Android to iOS.

But what you can do is inspire yourself from the work that you have done on Android (how you solved a specific problem) and also you could try to convert `Utils` classes (if possible).

- Long answer

  Android and iOS development principles are different (design patterns ...).

  Converting JAVA to Swift is not always correct and optimized.

  UX is different in both platforms (example: there is no Toast in iOS)

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert but, You can achieve it using **Kotlin Multiplatform Project**, where you can write business logic once for both of the platforms.

You can find more details about "How to do?" from the following reference:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html